# Django template values

Tags: python, django, templates

I am retrieving model object to my template and I am getting it like this:

```
value: [{'name_value9': 48}]
```

When filter the object in the view I am using '.values' like this:

```
...
name_value.values('name_value' + str(fn))
...
```

The reason for that is that I have `'name_value1`, `name_value2`, etc... and I need to get to the correct one.

How can I show in the template only the result (`value`) without the key (`name_value9`)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print values in your template like this:

```
{% obj in obj_list %}
    {% for key, value in obj.items %}
        {{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```